# How do I get a view to refresh after I delete a model from a collection?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have a view that is a list of phones. In the list, you can add or delete a phone. Here, for example, is the function called when a delete phone form is clicked on. The problem is that I want to navigate to the updated list once the phone is deleted. The way that I am using Backbone, that will mean refetching the collection of phones from the server, but I guess that's okay, as long as the list is updated. With the function below, the list is not refreshed.

```
      deletePhone: function (ev) {

            var that = this;
            ev.preventDefault();
            var phoneDetails = $(ev.currentTarget).serializeObject();
            var phone = new P.phone();
            phone.set({id: phoneDetails['phone-to-delete']});
            phone.destroy({

                  success: function(model, response, options) {
                    Backbone.history.navigate('phones', {trigger: true});
                  },
                  error: function(model, response, options) {
                    console.log("In error: ");
                  }


            });

      },
```

So how do I navigate to the updated list?

Answer (score 0):

Once you call delete on a model within a collection and that model is deleted successfully on the server, that model will trigger a 'destroy' event that will bubble up to the collection. The view just meeds to be told to listen to a destroy event on the collection, and then re-render once this happens. To do this, put this line of code in the initialization function of the view:

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'destroy', this.render);
```

This code will call the render function once a model in the collection has been deleted. Notice that it is not necessary to get the updated list from the server, as backbone has already removed it from the collection on the front end. Of course, if there is a possibility that the list has been changed by other clients, then grabbing it from the server again may be needed.

This may be better than placing a render call in the remove function itself the cover that case that a model is removed from the collection by other means.